# Macro as a parameter to another macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to pass the parameters to macro `SETBIT` with another predefined macro like this:

```
#define SETBIT(ADDRESS,BIT,N) {(N) ? (ADDRESS &= ~(1<<BIT)) : (ADDRESS |= (1<<BIT))}
#define DAC_SYNC PORTB,3,POS
SETBIT(DAC_SYNC);
```

However I receiver error:

> macro SETBIT requires 3 parameters only 1 given

There is an [article](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html) with the following recommendations:

*to prevent misnesting of arithmetic operations: `#define foo (a,b)` or `#define bar(x) lose((x))`*

But even though I still have an error. BTW, reading the article I've indicated I can make the following conclusion: preprocessor expands ALL macroses appearing. But actually it looks like macro `#define DAC_SYNC PORTB,3,POS` is not expanding by preprocessor.

Could anyone make more clear how the GCC's preprocessor works?

Answer (score 9):

This works:

```
#define SETBIT2(ADDRESS,BIT,N) ((N) ? (ADDRESS &= ~(1<<BIT)) : (ADDRESS |= (1<<BIT)))
#define SETBIT(PARAMS) SETBIT2(PARAMS)
#define PORTB 5
#define POS 7
#define DAC_SYNC PORTB,3,POS

int main() {
  int a = SETBIT(DAC_SYNC);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's worked!!! But actually I didn't get the point: why this solved the problem? Is there any clear article on the topic?

Comment: I would suggest `#define SETBIT(...) SETBIT2(__VA_ARGS__)` -- this way you can call `SETBIT` with a macro that expands to 3 args or with the 3 args directly.

Comment: @RomanMatveev: It works by adding an extra indirection that causes the `DAC_SYNC` macro to be expanded before parsing the arguments to `SETBIT2`.  C macro expansion works by first parsing the arguments, then expanding any macros in the arguments, then substituting the argments into the body, then rescanning the result for more macros to expand.  The order is very important!

Comment: OMG! Now declaration `SETBIT(PORTA,2,0)` not working :(((((((

Answer (score 4):

Just for the sake of completeness, that same manual you are linking to also states:

> The number of arguments you give must match the number of
>   parameters in the macro definition.  When the macro is expanded, each
>   use of a parameter in its body is replaced by the tokens of the
>   corresponding argument.

So ooga's example is a nice demonstration of how macro expansion works recursively, first the outer macro gets expanded, then the argument.